# Parse data JSON from Firebase Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I try to parse and assign data, which I am becoming from Firebase 
The structure in Firebase looks like this:

[image]

I try to fetch data from database and assign it to instance of class `Meal`:

```
ref = Database.database().reference()
        databaseHandle = ref.child("Meal").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            var downloadedName : String!
            var downloadedPhoto : String!
            var downloadedRating : Int!
            var downloadedSteps : Array <String>!
            var downloadedIngredients : [Dictionary <String, String>]!

            print(snapshot.value)
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, Any>{
                print("VALUES!!!")


                for key in dict.keys {

                    if let values = dict[key] as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                        print(values)

                        if let name = values["name"] as? String{
                            downloadedName = name
                        }

                        if let photo = values["photo"] as? String{
                            downloadedPhoto = photo
                        }

                        if let rating = values["rating"] as? Int{
                            downloadedRating = rating
                        }
                        if let steps = values["steps"] as? Array<String>{
                            downloadedSteps = steps
                        }
                        if let ingredients = values["ingredients"] as? [Dictionary <String, String>]{
                            downloadedIngredients = ingredients
                        }

                         let meal = Meal(name: downloadedName, photo: UIImage(named: downloadedPhoto), rating: downloadedRating, steps: downloadedSteps, ingredients: downloadedIngredients)           
                        self.meals.append(meal!);
                    }
                }
```

The Meal class itself looks like this:

```
class Meal {
    var name: String
    var photo: UIImage?
    var rating: Int
    var steps: Array<String>
    var ingredients: [Dictionary<String, String>]}
```

I get the first `print` - the whole data, so the connection with DB is OK, but as i try to assign it - nothing happens, no errors, no data (the second `print` with message `VALUES!!!` is not shown at all, what am I doing wrong?

Here is also what I get by first `print`

```
Optional(<__NSArrayM 0x600002fdaa60>(
{
    ingredients =     (
                {
            amount = 100;
            ingredient = milk;
            measurement = ml;
        },
                {
            amount = 120;
            ingredient = milk;
            measurement = ml;
        }
    );
    name = "Caprese Salad";
    photo = meal1;
    rating = 4;
    steps =     (
        test1,
        test11
    );
},
{
    ingredients =     (
                {
            amount = 100;
            ingredient = milk;
            measurement = ml;
        },
                {
            amount = 120;
            ingredient = milk;
            measurement = ml;
        }
    );
    name = "Chicken and Potatoes";
    photo = meal2;
    rating = 3;
    steps =     (
        test2,
        test22
    );
},
{
    ingredients =     (
                {
            amount = 100;
            ingredient = milk;
            measurement = ml;
        },
                {
            amount = 120;
            ingredient = milk;
            measurement = ml;
        }
    );
    name = "Pasta with Meatballs";
    photo = meal3;
    rating = 2;
    steps =     (
        test3,
        test33
    );
}
)
)
```

So, I assume, I retrieve the data in the false way at some point, how could i fix it?

Comment: You should use the Codable protocol.

Comment: `if let dict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, Any>{}`, so if `snapshot.value` is not a Dictionary where keys are `String` and values are "whatever", you won't pass that test. Alright? Print of "values": starts with `Optional(<__NSArrayM 0x600002fdaa60>(`. Yeah, clearly that's an Array, not a Dictionary. So because of ` as? Dictionary<String, Any>`, you don't get your second print.

Comment: @Larme What should I change in my data to make it as Dictionary?..

Comment: No. You misunderstood the structure of `snapshot.value`. So instead of trying to parse it as it was a Dictionary, parse it as it is an Array.

Comment: You want to turn your json into a swift object ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/RTC14wRr should do the trick. Parsing an array of dictionary, not a Dictionary, which is the real top level of your response. Also, avoid force unwrapp (using `!`), and the var declaration before the loop. Because currently if you missed an `if let`, you'd get the previous value, not a "default one". But you might want to use Codable (Swift 4+). Edit: Replace `values["someString"]` with `aValue["someString"]`, small copy/paste mistake.

Comment: @Larme it works! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
print(snapshot.value)
if let dict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, Any>{
    print("VALUES!!!")
    ....
}
```

You say that `print(snapshot.value)` is called but not `print("VALUES!!!")`.
Well, that means that `snapshot.value` or it isn't a `Dictionary` which keys are `String` objects and values are of type `Any`.

Now, let's see the output of `snapshot.value`:

```
Optional(<__NSArrayM 0x600002fdaa60> ...
```

`NSArrayM` => `NSMutableArray`, so `snapshot.value` is an `Array`, not a `Dictionary`. Of course then the `as? Dictionary` will fail!

So you need to treat it as an `Array`.

Quickly written:

```
if let array = snapshot.value as? [[String: Any]] {
    for aValue in array {
        let name = aValue["name"] as? String ?? "unnamed"
        let photoName = aValue["photo"] as? String ?? "noPhoto"
        let rating = aValue["rating"] as? Int ?? 0
        let steps = aValue["steps"] as? [String] ?? []
        let ingredients = aValue["ingredients"] as? [[String: String]] ?? [:]
        let meal = Meal(name: name, photo: UIImage(named: photoName), rating: rating, steps: steps, ingredients: ingredients)           
        self.meals.append(meal)
    }
}
```

What could also been wrong with your approach:

```
var downloadedName : String!
loop {
    if let name = values["name"] as? String {
        downloadedName = name
    }
    let meal = Meal(name: downloadedName, ...)
}
```

Well, if for the second value you didn't have a name (either because it's not a `String` or because the value doesn't exist), you `downloadedName` would have the value of the first one, but the rest of the values of the second one.

I used the approach:

```
let name = aValue["name"] as? String ?? "unnamed"
```

Meaning, that if it's nil, it gets a default value.
But you could decide to accept only valid one, by a `guard let` or `if let` potentially on all the subvalues.

For instance:

```
if let name = aValue["name"] as? String,
   let let photoName = aValue["photo"] as? String, 
   ... {
    let meal = Meal(name: name, photo: UIImage(named: photoName)
    self.meals.append(meal)
}
```

And since your `Meal.init()` seems to return an optional, you could add it also in the `if let` and avoid the force unwrap of `meal`.